# Dados da DataTable não são exibidos, mesmo com loading do ArrayList sendo executado corretamente

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Galera, estou carregando uma dataTable do JSF com um ArrayList, mas o resultado não é exibido de maneira alguma, segue como está meu código:

index.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h1>Novo Jogo</h1>
    <j:form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Dados do Jogo</legend>
            <j:panelGrid columns="2">
                <j:outputLabel value="Titulo:" for="titulo" />
                <j:inputText id="titulo" value="#{meusJogosBean.mj.titulo}" />
                <j:outputLabel value="Desenvolvedora:" for="desenvolvedora" />
                <j:inputText id="desenvolvedora"
                    value="#{meusJogosBean.mj.desenvolvedora}" />
                <j:outputLabel value="Ano Lancamento:" for="ano_lancamento" />
                <j:inputText id="ano_lancamento"
                    value="#{meusJogosBean.mj.ano_lancamento}" />
                <j:outputLabel value="plataforma:" for="plataforma" />
                <j:inputText id="plataforma" value="#{meusJogosBean.mj.plataforma}" />
                <j:commandButton value="Gravar" action="#{meusJogosBean.gravar}">
                </j:commandButton>
            </j:panelGrid>
        </fieldset>
    </j:form>
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form id="formTabelaJogos">
        <p:dataTable value="#{meusJogosBean.jogos}" var="j" id="tabelaJogos" lazy="true">
                <p:column headerText="Título" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{j.titulo}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="text" />
                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>

</h:body>
</html>
```

MeusJogosBean.java

```
package model;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import model.MeusJogos;
import model.DAO;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MeusJogosBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MeusJogos mj = new MeusJogos();

    public List<MeusJogos> getJogos() {
        return new DAO<MeusJogos>(MeusJogos.class).listaTodos();
    }

    public MeusJogos getMj() {
        return mj;
    }

    public void setMj(MeusJogos mj) {
        this.mj = mj;
    }

    public void gravar() {
        System.out.println("Gravando jogo: " + this.mj.getTitulo());
        new DAO<MeusJogos>(MeusJogos.class).adiciona(mj);

    }


}
```

MeusJogos.Java

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MeusJogos {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String titulo;
    private String desenvolvedora;
    private String ano_lancamento;
    private String plataforma;

    public MeusJogos() {

    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    public String getDesenvolvedora() {
        return desenvolvedora;
    }
    public void setDesenvolvedora(String desenvolvedora) {
        this.desenvolvedora = desenvolvedora;
    }
    public String getAno_lancamento() {
        return ano_lancamento;
    }
    public void setAno_lancamento(String ano_lancamento) {
        this.ano_lancamento = ano_lancamento;
    }
    public String getPlataforma() {
        return plataforma;
    }
    public void setPlataforma(String plataforma) {
        this.plataforma = plataforma;
    }

}
```

DAO.java

```
package model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

public class DAO<T> {

    private final Class<T> classe;

    public DAO(Class<T> classe) {
        this.classe = classe;
    }

    public void adiciona(T t) {

        // consegue a entity manager
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();

        // abre transacao
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        // persiste o objeto
        em.persist(t);

        // commita a transacao
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        // fecha a entity manager
        em.close();
    }

    public void remove(T t) {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        em.remove(em.merge(t));

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    public void atualiza(T t) {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        em.merge(t);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    public List<T> listaTodos() {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(classe);
        query.select(query.from(classe));

        List<T> lista = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        System.out.println(lista.size());
        em.close();
        return lista;

    }

    public T buscaPorId(Integer id) {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        T instancia = em.find(classe, id);
        em.close();
        return instancia;
    }

    public int contaTodos() {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        long result = (Long) em.createQuery("select count(n) from jogo n")
                .getSingleResult();
        em.close();

        return (int) result;
    }

    public List<T> listaTodosPaginada(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(classe);
        query.select(query.from(classe));

        List<T> lista = em.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(firstResult)
                .setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();

        em.close();
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual o erro que a IDE informa? Poste o erro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está usando o atributo `lazy="true"` é necessário tratar a modelagem de dados com a classe `LazyDataModel`.

O atributo `lazy` faz com que a paginação seja "real", ou seja, faz com que a cada alteração das páginas do dataTable faça uma nova requisição até o back end, chegando até o banco com pelo menos duas informações: o index da linha a partir da onde deve retornar os dados e a quantidade de dados que deve ser retornada. Por exemplo: se você tem uma query que resulta em 100 registros e sua paginação no dataTable for de 10 itens por página, quando o usuário clicar na segunda página as informações `11` e `10` serão enviadas, sendo o `11` o index de a partir de onde deve retornar os dados e o `10` a quantidade de dados que deve ser retornada.

Normalmente utiliza-se o `lazy` quando estamos trabalhando com uma base de dados considerável. Para poucos registros ás vezes (repito, **ás vezes**) é melhor deixar a paginação "falsa", onde na hora de carregar o dataTable, que ele já seja carregado por completo e a paginação fica apenas na view.

---

Se você quiser usar o `lazy`, você precisa criar uma classe que herde de `LazyDataModel<T>`. Por exemplo:

```
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;

public class LazyJogosDataModel extends LazyDataModel<MeusJogos> { }
```

Nessa classe você precisará sobrescrever (pelo menos) o método `load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)`. (Se não me engano existe uma sobrecarga desse método que recebe apenas os dois primeiros parâmetros)

Num primeiro momento é um pouco complicado/chato entender como funciona. Mas depois que pega o jeito fica tranquilo.

Aconselho fortemente que você dê uma olhada [nesse exemplo no site do PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml). Ele é muito bom e bem completo.

Answer (score 1):

Não use List quando estiver usando lazy = true. 
coloca assim:

```
LazyDataModel<MeusJogos>  = new LazyDataModel(){

  public load (...){
    DAO<MeusJogos>(MeusJogos.class).listaTodos();

  }
}
```

vai resolver seu problema